# Issue with Database Connect from K8s pod

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-rds, amazon-eks

I have successfully deployed a pod and service for a Spring-Boot-API to **AWS-Kubernetes-Cluster (EKS)**.

The App connects to a **MySQL RDS**. RDS and EKS are in **different VPCs**.  I configured a Peering connection and also the routes in the VPCs.

The **database is public** and I can connect from my local environment.

For the cluster, I configured the **environment variables** in the deployment-YAML and injected them with config-map (secrets for user and pwd)

When the pod starts I get the following error:
`java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'admin'@'172.31.35.70' (using password: YES)`

I guess that this is a network issue, as the username is resolved correctly!

Comment: Normally if it was a network issue you'd get a network error. You're getting an authentication error, implying that you can actually connect to confirm your access is denied

Comment: That is a helpful hint. But for what reason the user is correctly injected and the password obviously not?

Comment: I don’t know but it seems to rule out network

Answer (score 0):

**Rule number 1** never make your database public. If you look in the logs, hackers are probably brute-forcing it right now.

The fact you are getting an AccessDenied, suggests the networking is correct, but something is wrong with the password you are supplying.

I would create a bastion in the same subnet as the k8s pod and connect to the database from there with the username and password.

Comment: It is only a test-db! As I wrote I can connect from application to database outside of k8. I would like to keep separate VPCs and looking for a solution for that.

Comment: You said you can connect to the DB from your local. I am saying connect to the database from an instance inside the subnet of your k8s application so that you can verify if it is a network issue.

Comment: as @Nick.McDermaid supposed -it is not a network issue.

Comment: I tested this by **stopping the database** - then I get a different error, pointing on a network issue. The error is that the **password is not correct**. I deployed the password with a **secret.map where the password is base64-.encoded**. 

It seems that the decoding produces a different result or maybe it is not decoded at all. Interestingly the user (also from the secret-map) is correctly decoded (see error message which says that admin@... has no access). 

To test this I put the credentials in the configmap (not encoded)